# What happens if I mount multiple devices at the same path in chroots?

Tags: mount, chroot

I'm trying to understand what happens if multiple change roots mount to my host's `/proc` directory.

```
sudo chroot mychroot1
mount -t proc proc /proc

sudo chroot mychroot2
mount -t proc proc /proc
```

Does `mychroot2` get all of `/proc` and 'kick off' `mychoort1`?

http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount

Answer (score 1):

If you're running the `mount` commands inside the chroots, then from the perspective of the outermost root, there will be `proc` filesystems mounted on `/proc`, `…/mychroot1/proc` and `…/mychroot2/proc`. There's no problem with that, you can access exactly the same files through any of the mount points. No “kicking off” is involved.

A number of files under `/proc` indicate paths in one way or another. These paths are from the root directory of the process that reads them. Which mount point is used doesn't matter. From the outermost root, you'll see exactly the same things in `/proc/123/fd` and `/mychroot1/proc/123/fd`. Of course inside the chroot at `/mychroot1` only the `/proc` inside that root can be accessed, but you could mount `/proc` elsewhere and still see the same files.